# How to connect MsAccess database existing in windows folder using Kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes

I have an **MSAccess** database in my local windows. and I need to connect it with java code using Kubernetes.

I tried to use the below:

```
jdbc:ucanaccess:///run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Users/Public/fdb/F_B_1_2.mdb;jackcessOpener=com.sms-manager.mobile_app.mobileapp.manage.CryptCodecOpener
```

But it's not working with me.

it's giving java error database not existing.

Comment: Obviously, your Java app in the container cannot find the db file. Maybe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930940/how-to-allow-a-kubernetes-job-access-to-a-file-on-host

Answer (score 0):

Is your java application running in container and trying to connect to ms access db which is in another machine? if yes then you can create [Kubernetes service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and endpoint of your db server or external name of db server.  Choose suitable JDBC and ODBC driver to connect to MS Access Database